# How can I color a radar (spiderweb) with shading fill, just like colorbar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, fill

I am trying to fill a radar plot (also called spiderweb) with a shading fill, just like what can be seen with the colorbar feature in 3Dplot.

The radar plot assesses 3 dimensions, that are rated from 0 to 5 (0= none, 1= very bad, ... 5= very good) ; and 5 color have also been defined, corresponding to each of theses ratings.

I would like to color the inside of the shape depending on the distance of each point from the origin  using the grading color scale with a shade for colors transitions.

Is this feasible with the colorbar function or any or function of TikZ?

The code of the radar plot and color:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{green-dark}{rgb}{0,0.2,0}

\definecolor{very-good}{RGB}{25,125,90}
\definecolor{good}{RGB}{90,170,130}
\definecolor{neutral}{RGB}{240,170,50}
\definecolor{bad}{RGB}{180,120,110}
\definecolor{very-bad}{RGB}{160,50,40}


\begin{document}
%% Spider chart
%% ------------
    \newcommand{\axisrated}{3} % dimensions
    \newcommand{\scale}{5} % rating scale for each dimension

    \newdimen\INsize
        \INsize=3.5cm 
    \newdimen\OUTsize
        \OUTsize=4.5cm
    
    % Angle between rated dimensions
    \newcommand{\Aradar}{360/\axisrated}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw the spider web
        \foreach \Xradar in {1,...,\axisrated}{
            \draw (\Xradar*\Aradar:0) -- (\Xradar*\Aradar:\INsize);
        }
        
        \foreach \Yradar in {0,...,\scale}{
            % Axis
            \foreach \Xradar in {1,...,\axisrated}{
                \path (\Xradar*\Aradar:\Yradar*\INsize/\scale) coordinate (P\Xradar-\Yradar);
                \fill (P\Xradar-\Yradar) circle (1pt);
            };
            
            % Grid
            \draw [opacity=0.2] (0:\Yradar*\INsize/\scale)
            \foreach \Xradar in {1,...,\axisrated}{
            -- (\Xradar * \Aradar : \Yradar*\INsize/\scale)
            } -- cycle;
            
            % Axis labels
            \path (1*\Aradar:\OUTsize) node (L1) {Axis 1};
            \path (2*\Aradar:\OUTsize) node (L2) {Axis 2};
            \path (3*\Aradar:\OUTsize) node (L3) {Axis 3};
        }
        
        
        % Draw the result
        \draw [color=green-dark,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.7]
            (P1-1) --
            (P2-5) --
            (P3-3) -- cycle;

        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this kind of plot there is the package [tkz-kiviat](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat) of @Alain Matthes

Comment: @Alain Matthes Is it possible to add gradient/shading at the graph using tkz-kiviat?

Comment: I was not aware of this package, thank you Alain Matthes, i will dig into it :)